# When using Deployment Risk Analytics, what types of criteria can I use?

Tags: ibm-cloud, deployment-risk-analytics

In IBM Bluemix Deployment Risk Analytics, I want to create different criteria for my tools to check and determine whether the users can move forward to the next step in the deployment pipeline.  What are my options for the scope of those criteria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its current release, Deployment Risk Analytics criteria is scoped for the user organization.  All users and applications of the same Bluemix organization have access to the criteria.